# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpa-test

Tags: java, jpa, entity

My error text:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpa-test
```

I have tried all the ideas on this question from here but is not working. I still get same error.
I dont know what to do..Please dont give me links to questions like this. I really tried all the ideas but still not working
persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="jpa-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.licenta.ascourses.model.Utilizator</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:test.db" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Entity:

```
   package com.licenta.ascourses.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Utilizator implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_utilizator;
    private String username;
    private String parola;
    private String email;
    private String nume;
    private String prenume;
    private int cod;
    private int status;

    public Utilizator(String nume, String prenume){
        this.nume=nume;
        this.prenume=prenume;

    }



    public Utilizator(String username, String parola, String email, String nume,
            String prenume, int cod, int status) {


        this.username = username;
        this.parola = parola;
        this.email = email;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.cod = cod;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Utilizator(String email, String nume, String prenume, int status) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.status = status;
    }



    public Utilizator(String string) {
        this.username=string;
    }



    public int getId_utilizator() {
        return id_utilizator;
    }

    public void setId_utilizator(int id_utilizator) {
        this.id_utilizator = id_utilizator;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getParola() {
        return parola;
    }

    public void setParola(String parola) {
        this.parola = parola;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }

    public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(int cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public int isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {

        this.status = (status==1)?1:0;


    }

    public int getStatus() {


        return (this.status==1)?1:0;

    }

}
```

My test class:

```
package com.licenta.ascourses.DbConnection;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.licenta.ascourses.model.Utilizator;

public class JPATest {

    public static void performJPA() {

        // Creating objects representing some products
        Utilizator user1=new Utilizator("andrei", "parola", "jean@jean", "jean", "popescu", 123, 1);
        Utilizator user2=new Utilizator("miu", "parola2", "ana@ana", "ana", "cartianu", 234, 1);

        // Connecting to the database through EntityManagerFactory
        // connection details loaded from persistence.xml
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-test");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // Creating a new transaction
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

        tx.begin();

        // Persisting the product entity objects
        em.persist(user1);
        em.persist(user2);

        tx.commit();

        // Querying the contents of the database using JPQL query
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Utilizatori p");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Utilizator> results = q.getResultList();

        System.out.println("List of products\n----------------");

        for (Utilizator user : results) {

            System.out.println(user.getNume() + " (id=" + user.getId_utilizator() + ")");
        }

        // Closing connection
        em.close();

        emf.close();
    }




}
```

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml located in your CLASSPATH? Which JPA provider jars and JPA API jar do you have in the CLASSPATH? A simple search on here for that error message would show up pages of people asking the same question and they were always referred to what is in the CLASSPATH and where

Answer (score 0):

You need a JPA provider in your classpath. Example providers: [Hibernate, Toplink, Apache OpenJPA, EclipseLink.](https://www.google.com/search?q=jpa%20providers&oq=jpa%20providers&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2049j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

To learn about Java's classpath, see: [Java Tutorial on Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: there is no such thing as "Apache OpenDB"

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks, changed to OpenJPA.

Comment: @CobianuA Maven is providing you with compile-time dependencies. At runtime, the JVM needs to know where your class files and .jar files (runtime dependencies) are located. This is often done with the `classpath`command line  parameter, or the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html